# Reference in place of getters?

Tags: c++

in C++ is it a bad practice to use reference in place of getters?

for example:

```
class X
{
    int mP;
 public:
    const int& P;
    X():P(mP){}
};
```

and later

```
X xl;
int h = xl.P;
```

Comment: The above code is extremely dangerous, as you lack a copy constructor, and the copy constructor you get by default does not do what you want done.  :)

Comment: Why not make `mP` public?

Comment: The whole point of getters/setters is that the object knows when data changes; its a level of abstraction. If you are trying to get around this, do what @juanchopanza says.

Comment: I do not have any requirement like this but, I was just wondering if this can do any harm. 
@Yakk will a copy constructor come into picture while initializing a reference??

Comment: @user2173884 If you interested in such questions, then you are ready to pick theese classic books: *Effective C++* series by Scott Meyers and *Exceptional C++* series by Herb Sutter. [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1)

Comment: Yes.  `X alice;  X bob = alice;` will call the copy constructor, and `bob.P` will be a reference to `alice.mP`.  What worse, `X make_X(); X bob = make_X();` will result in using `bob.P` being undefined behavior.  Storing references in a `class` or `struct` is dangerous, as assignment and copy rarely does what you want it to do, especially if the type isn't "all reference" or "all non-reference".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of this is good:

```
class X { public: int x; };
class X {
    private: int m_x;
    public: const int& get() const { return m_x; }
    public: void set(const int& other)  { m_x = other; } 
};
class X {
    private: int m_x;
    public: const int& x() const { return m_x; }
    public: void x(const int& other)  { m_x = other; } 
};
class X {
    private: int m_x;
    public: const int& x() const { return m_x; }
    public: int& x()  { return m_x; }
};
```

Pick one, it's a design decision.

Having 'const int& x' to publish the private member will work:

```
class X {
    private: int m_x;
    public: const int& x;
    public: X() : m_x(0), x(m_x) {}
    // Take care for copy and assignment
};
```

The cost is a larger memory footprint.

Comment: How would this cost larger memory footprint?

Comment: @user2173884 the class stores x plus the reference to x

Comment: I guess Reference do not take any memory. they are resolved during compile time, they are just an alias in variable table created by compiler which does not exist after linking.

Comment: @user2173884 Nope - they take the same space as a pointer does.

Comment: Indeed. I just checked it actually take pointer size. Valid point to not to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Just think about refactoring to make the access thread safe, that won't work well this way and require a lot of changes in the client classes/functions.

If you have class members, that are guaranteed not to be changed over lifetime of the instance, you can simply provide `const int P;` and initialize it properly in your class' constructors.

If the value is to be visible class wide use a `static const int P;`

In any other case use a public getter:

```
int P() const; // a return type of 'const int &' would be redundant
```

1st shot implementation:

```
int X::P() const
{
    return mP;
}
```

Thread safe implementation:

```
class X {
{
    // ...
private:
    // ...
    mutable std::mutex internalDataGuard;
};

int X::P() const
{
    std::lock(internalDataGuard);
    return mP;
}
```

Comment: @user2173884 Depend's on your use case. But if you abstract it out in your designs early (as you don't do with `public const int& P;`), will make it easier to scale out later. I think I have explained the exceptional cases well.